# How to get datepicker value with formcontrol

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datepicker

I have a problem with storing value to formcontrol using datepicker. Here is the example:

```
<div class="col-12 scol-sm-6 col-md-3 col-xl-3">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>Эхлэх огноо</label>
      <input
         id="salaryTransferStartDate"
         class="form-control daterange-basic"
         #salaryTransferStartDate
      />
   </div>
</div>
```

In my `ts` file:

```
$("#salaryTransferStartDate").daterangepicker({
      singleDatePicker: true,
      startDate: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
      locale: {
        format: "YYYY-MM-DD"
      },
      onClose: dateText => {
        this.configurationForm
          .get("salaryTransferStartDate")
          .setValue(dateText);
      }
    });
```

But my `formControl` value = `null`. What am i doing wrong ? I am using angular 7.

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to avoid use of Javascript in angular.

In this case on select of datepicker usually change not reflected in Model as you are not typing values using keyboard.

can you try:-

```
    $('#salaryTransferStartDate').datepicker({
      format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
      autoclose: true
    })
    .on('changeDate', function(e){
      e.target.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
      e.target.dispatchEvent(new Event('change')); 

    });;


     <input  type="text" size="5" maxlength="100" id="yuyuy"
                        [ngModel]="fromDate" class="form-control cal_date"
                        placeholder="Enter {{displayName}}">
```

The answer is for template driven. you can also test in reactive and let me know. I also got stuck in similar situation and trigger input work for me. If have issues let me know

Comment: I tried this https://imgur.com/a/UNbGezN but this gives undefined error.

Comment: can you create a demo on stackblitz ?  You are not triggering input event. like this e.target.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
e.target.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));

Comment: I am not using ngModel